# How can I stop my iPad from asking me about logging in to iCloud?

Tags: ipad, icloud

I do not want to use the iCloud in any way. I do not want it running at all. I want it gone. How do I stop it from asking to log in? It is asking every 10 seconds. It has made my iPad unusable. How do I get rid of it so I can use my iPad?

Comment: If you skip adding an Apple ID and iCloud when you set up a new iPad, when does it ask you for logging in?

Answer (score 3):

Have you turned off all iCloud features?  To do that on your iOS device’s Home screen, go to Settings > iCloud, then tap to turn on or off iCloud features.

More information here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2613